# Transaction.Current being cleared after running Powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, transactions

The below code (just a stripped down example for showing the crux of the issue. The real code is doing a lot more) will throw an error on machines running Powershell versions above 2.

```
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.AddScript("");
        powershell.Invoke();
    }
}
```

The error being thrown is:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Transaction.Current has changed inside of the TransactionScope.

After the using statement that creates the powershell instance exits, the 'Transaction.Current' becomes null (If your machine has powershell version 2, Transaction.Current still retains its transaction). I've been able to stop it from throwing an exception by wrapping the powershell using statement inside of a suppressed TransactionScope:

```
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
        using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.AddScript("");
            powershell.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

But I want whatever powershell script that is run to be apart of the transaction instead of non transactional, so the above is not an ideal solution.

Any other ideas?